# Parse all XML text using XMLPullParser

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, android-xmlpullparser

I have a question that is similar to `[this one here][1]` 
I have read tutorials about XMLPullParser and do not seem to get this one.

I have an XML tag I want to parse using XMLPullParser

```
<dt>
: <sx>outcome</sx>
<sx>result</sx>
</dt>
```

I want to get the result ": outcome result."
Because I am reading this XML from an online base. It may change. For instance :

```
<dt>
:degree or measure of
<d_link>succeeding</d_link>
</dt>
```

The question is how do I parse and get all the text in the tag "dt" irrespective of the name of the tags in it?

This is what I have tried but it is not working.

```
while (parser.next() != END_TAG){
            if (parser.getEventType() != TEXT)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if (parser.getEventType() == TEXT)
            {
                Log.d("Text", parser.getText()+" in the likelihood");
                stringBuilder.append(parser.getText());
                parser.next();
            }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something similar to:

```
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
{
    String tagname = parser.getName();
    switch (eventType) 
    {
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("dt")) 
            {
                 // create a new instance of DTClass
                 dt= new DTClass();
            }
            break;

        case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
             text = parser.getText();
             break;

         case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
             if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("dt")) {
                  // add DTClass object to list
                  dts.add(dt);
             } 
             else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("sx")) 
             {
                  dt.setSX(text);
             } 

             break;

         default:
             break;
     }
     eventType = parser.next();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Artur. The issue is I have no control of what the sub tag could be. It could be "sx" at this point for a particular query, it could be something else later. How do I handle this case?

Comment: Thanks Artur. I have another question similar to the above. How do I reach you please?

Comment: bestin-it.com find me on my blog

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Checking your blog now

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that xml is properly formatted you can change the code to remember opened tag, value and when tag is ended add a value to the dictionary/list like below:

```
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
{
    String tagname = parser.getName();
    String detectedTag = "" ;
    String valueTag = "" ;
    switch (eventType) 
    {
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("dt")) 
            {
                 // create a new instance of DTClass
                 // move this line to the end tag
                 //dt= new DTClass();
            }
            detectedTag = tagname ;
            break;

        case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
             valueTag = parser.getText();                 
             break;

         case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
             if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(detectedTag)) {                      
                  // create a new instance of DTClass                      
                  dt= new DTClass();

                  // set value
                  dt.setValue(valueTag);

                  // add DTClass object to list od dictionary
                  dts.add(dt);
             } 
             else 
             {
                  // clear tag and value tag
                  detectedTag = "" ;
                  valueTag = "";
             } 

             break;

         default:
             break;
     }
     eventType = parser.next();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now. Even the first answer you gave worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Here you are 